# Is an app with +90 screens ok for react native?

Tags: react-native

I have a native app on iOS with >90 screens.

My client wants an android version and we might use reactnative.

Now the question: Is react native ok for an app with >90 screens?

there are no special navigation or animations effects.

I was reading about [airbnb dropping react native](https://medium.com/airbnb-engineering/react-native-at-airbnb-f95aa460be1c)
They had many reasons, one being the number of screens they use > 100... but with special customizations.

So, is it safe to use react native in my not so specialized app with lots of screens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say this is more personal opinion than a technical answer. Either way, I'll give mine.

You're not likely to see any performance deficit by using a high number of screens, especially if they all carry little amounts of logic, however from a design point of view it could get quite messy - is there a reason you'll need such a high number of screens?

You're also likely to find your navigation stacks become incredibly confusing with so many screens in each, you'd end up with a huge file and readability could become difficult.

Could you design in a way such that a screen can dynamically display this content rather than moving from screen to screen each time?

I'd say, unless you're looking at building an app as technically complicated as AirBnB, you could cut down the numbers. I built the mobile app for a large UK retailer and we managed this in less than 20 screens so it's definitely do-able.